# react-native-dotenv does not reflect changes in .env

Tags: react-native

I already tried a well-known resolution of this problem--"*change every file which imports from .env*". It worked first few times, but now it has no effect.
I'd appreciate it if somebody shed some lights on my questions.

- Why the solution stopped functioning?
- Why it worked first few times?
- Is there any other way to solve this problem?

.env

```
REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL=http://10.0.2.2:3000/v8/api
```

constants.js

```
import {REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL} from "@env"
export const apiBaseUrl = REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL
//I added this sentence so that my app recognizes changes in .env
```

App.js

```
import React,{useEffect} from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  Alert
} from 'react-native';
import { apiBaseUrl } from './constants.js';

const App = () => {
  useEffect(()=>{
    Alert.alert(apiBaseUrl)
//The above alert should display http://10.0.2.2:3000/v8/api, but it displays the previous value of REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL
  },[])
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Hey</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
export default App
```

I tried following solutions, but it didn't work;

- restart metoro
- rebuild project by npx react-native run-android
- wipe data in ADV

Comment: Did you rerun your npm run android command?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I did it. I just edited my post and listed all solutions I tried.

Comment: hi! react-native-dotenv maintainer here. Can you please show your babel config?